# Best Practices for reusable hooks in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am new to rspec and we are using it for test automation for our application.  I have three hooks that are reused in every rspec test.  The hooks call a number modules that launch are used to launch & log into the site plus some other usable methods.

I have created a hooks.rb file and placed those hooks in there and call it within the rspec test but now I have lost the ability to call the instance variables that relate to the methods I need.  I could globalize the variables but I have read its not a good idea to do so.

Does anyone have any insight on what the best approach would be?

**I am including code example.**

```
before(:all) do
   < this before hook include making files available and initialization browser >
   ** very section
end

after(:all) do
   @client.quit
end

before(:each) do
  @page.goto
end
```

** I have to include this in every spec file and would not like to have to.  One call to the location so it is included for any spec.

Thank you,

Joe

So, my spec_helper.rb consist of the following information:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:all) do
        require_relative '../../lib/env'
        filedir = File.expand_path('../../etc',File.dirname(__FILE__))
        config = Matr::Configuration.new("#{filedir}/config.yaml", ENV["M_ENV"] || "development")
        @client = config.construct_selenium_driver "Insight: Login"
        @client.window.resize_to(1280,720)
        @page = Matr::Pages::Insight::LoginPage.new(@client)
        @account_page = Matr::Pages::Insight::InsightPage.new(@client)
        @choose_account = Matr::Pages::Insight::ChooseAccount.new(@client)
        @logout = Matr::Pages::Insight::LogOut.new(@client)
        @nav_bar = Matr::Pages::Insight::NavBar.new(@client)
        @db = Matr::Models::DB.new
        @manage_campaigns = Matr::Pages::Insight::ManageCampaignsPage.new(@client)
   end
end
```

Comment: On this site, it's always best to show your work.  Copy and paste your code with comments and use the {} button to indent it appropriately.  You'll get much more interest and better answers if you do.  See other questions for many examples. Good luck.

Comment: @R_G  I have included an example of our code that needs to be included in every spec file.

Answer (score 2):

You can define hooks for all examples when you configure rspec in your spec_helper.rb

For example you could do

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:all) do
    ...
  end
end
```

If you don't actually need this for all specs then you can use rspec's metadata filters. For example, to apply to all of the request specs you'd do

```
config.before(:all, type: :request) do
  ...
end
```

To only run against the specs with type :request. You can also make up your own metadata keys, so if you did

```
config.before(:all, browser: true) do
  ...
end
```

Then that before(:all) would run for example groups created in this way:

```
describe "something", browser: true do
...
end
```

Comment: above you will see my the lines of code that require_relative '../../lib/env' rb file.  In this file i require the necessary gems and other files.  So when i run the spec test i get an error stating 'LoadError: cannot load such file -- /Users/<my_name>/Documents/project/lib/env' can you require a file like this from the spec_helper?

Comment: Sure you can. If you have just moved that block across from one of your specs you might have to adjust the path, seing as your spec helper is probably higher up in the directory structure than the individual specs

Comment: Yes. that was it, now i am running into an error with config.yaml doesn't exist or not readable.  Still researching haven't anything yet.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  Got it working and it makes a huge difference.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using [shared examples](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-examples)? Generally, you should not have to roll your own approach to creating reusable modules.